# Coin toss simulation with winner getting better odds in next toss

Tags: probability, python, simulation

I'm sure this must have been done before but I have a coin toss simulation between two players, the variation being that, if a player wins, their chances of winning the next toss go up by a very small amount (and if they lose, their chances go down). Python code for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_wins = 0
b_wins = 0
a_win_odds = 0.5
win_odds_incr = 0.0001
trial_count = 0
run_count = 0
runs = 50
trials = 50000
run_data = []
a_win_odds_rec = []
max_a_win_odds_per_run = 0
max_a_win_odds = 0

while run_count < runs:
    a_win_odds_rec = []
    trial_count = 0
    a_wins = 0
    b_wins = 0
    a_win_odds = 0.5
    max_a_win_odds_per_run = 0

    while trial_count < trials:
        trial_count += 1
        res = np.random.random()
        if res <= a_win_odds:
            a_win_odds = min(a_win_odds + win_odds_incr, 1.0)
            a_wins += 1
        else:
            a_win_odds = max(a_win_odds - win_odds_incr, 0.0)
            b_wins += 1

        max_a_win_odds_per_run = max(max_a_win_odds_per_run, a_win_odds)
        a_win_odds_rec.append(a_win_odds)

    if a_win_odds < 0.5:
        max_a_win_odds = max(max_a_win_odds_per_run, max_a_win_odds)
        run_count += 1
        run_data.append(a_win_odds_rec)

print('A wins: %s' % a_wins)
print('B wins: %s' % b_wins)
print('A win odds: %s' % a_win_odds)
print('Maximum A win odds: %s' % max_a_win_odds)

x_values = np.arange(0, trial_count, 1)
count = 0
for run in run_data:
    count += 1
    plt.plot(x_values, run, label="run %s" % count, color='black', alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

This image shows the results of 50 runs with 50000 trials each:

[image]

In most cases I've seen, the odds of player A winning go to either 0 or 1.0 within the trial range. It looks like you can get up to about a 0.516 chance of winning before experiencing a reversal of fortune.

My thinking was to test whether even a tiny advantage can compound over time (e.g., social advantage) and it very much looks it does. I'm guessing this is a known phenomenon but does anyone know what it's called, or where I can find out more about it?

Comment: If you have access to a copy of Feller _An introduction to probability theory and its applications_ then chapter III section 4 _Last visits and long leads_ treats this sort of issue.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey, I'll check it out!